# Include auto switch in my fade out script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this script on my site for my Slider.
I would like the slider to automatically switch between the tabs. I have it working on the click event but I need it to rotate between the tabs at a set interval. 
can anyone help me would be very nice?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
            return false;
     });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div style="float:left; width:290px; height:243px;">
    <ul class="tabs">{loop:navigation}
        <li>    <a style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;" href="#tab{navigation:id}">
                {navigation:headline}<br />
                {navigation:text}
            </a>

        </li>{stop:navigation}</ul>
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:558px; height:243px;">{loop:specials}
    <div id="tab{specials:id}" class="tab_content"> <a href="http://{specials:url}" title=""><img src="{page:path}{specials:pic}" width="{specials:width}" height="{specials:height}" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    {stop:specials}
</div>
```

Comment: I will understand.....

On a serious note, what are you trying to achieve? This does not make sense until you show us some markup and describe your problem better.

Comment: I use this script on my site for my Slider http://team-whitex.de/2be/index.php.
By clicking it changes, but he wants also automatically switch the tabs.

Comment: Can you copy paste the HTML code that this Javascript is referring to? Its better to not post links to websites

Comment: i was pasted the HTML code. what can you do with it?

Comment: Is there a script/plugin you use for the slider? if you do, can you post the name or link?

Comment: i used the script for clansphere cms http://team-whitex.de/2be/templates/2beascension/javascript/tabs.js look the slider on this link http://team-whitex.de/2be/index.php?mod=news&action=recent

Comment: Google `setInterval()` and learn how to use it. Then use it to change tabs every few seconds.

Comment: Heres a fiddle which works with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/66WTS/

Comment: Its not correct. With your code stackerr switch automatical the content tab but tab navi li must automatical switch

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/66WTS/2/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way from here (or a quickfix) is to trigger the click function on an interval:

```
setInterval(function(){ $("ul.tabs li").click(); }, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

`.click()` is the same as `.trigger('click')`, so you can use the one you like more.